# I am getting Error "There is no row at position 0" from code below

Tags: vb.net

```
Private Sub Button3_Click (ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click

    If txtID.Text = "" Then
        MsgBox("Please input a valid Employee code to load a corresponding record", MsgBoxStyle.Information)
    Else
        dbProvider = "Provider=Microsoft.Ace.OLEDB.12.0;"
        dbSource = "Data Source = C:\Users\Blessing\Documents\IBCARIP.accdb;Persist Security Info=False"
        con.ConnectionString = dbProvider & dbSource
        con.Open()
        sql = "select * from Calculator where " _
            & "EmpCode = " & " '" & txtID.Text & "'"

        da = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(sql, con)
        da.Fill(ds, "IBCARIP")
        lblSAI.Text = ds.Tables("IBCARIP").Rows(inc).Item("SName") & ds.Tables("IBCARIP").Rows(inc).Item("FName")
        lblRate.Text = ds.Tables("IBCARIP").Rows(inc).Item("NRate")
        lblOT.Text = ds.Tables("IBCARIP").Rows(inc).Item("OTRate")
        lblBnk.Text = ds.Tables("IBCARIP").Rows(inc).Item("BName") & ".." & ds.Tables("IBCARIP").Rows(inc).Item("ANumber") & ".." & ds.Tables("IBCARIP").Rows(inc).Item("AType")
        con.Close()
        ds.Tables("IBCARIP").DataSet.Clear()
        MaxRows = ds.Tables("IBCARIP").Rows.Count
        'inc = 0
    End If
End Sub
```

The message comes when i enter a wrong or non-existent Employee code in txtID.text

how can i solve tha problem

Answer (score 1):

try as below

you should always check dataset table and rows count

i am not much familiar with vb .net(i am in C#) but i think following is good to go

```
    If txtID.Text = "" Then
        MsgBox("Please input a valid Employee code to load a corresponding record", MsgBoxStyle.Information)
    Else
        dbProvider = "Provider=Microsoft.Ace.OLEDB.12.0;"
        dbSource = "Data Source = C:\Users\Blessing\Documents\IBCARIP.accdb;Persist Security Info=False"
        con.ConnectionString = dbProvider & dbSource
        con.Open()
        sql = "select * from Calculator where " _
            & "EmpCode = " & " '" & txtID.Text & "'"

        da = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(sql, con)
        da.Fill(ds, "IBCARIP")
        If ds.Tables.Count > 0 AndAlso ds.Tables("IBCARIP").Rows.Count >0 Then
            lblSAI.Text = ds.Tables("IBCARIP").Rows(inc).Item("SName") & ds.Tables("IBCARIP").Rows(inc).Item("FName")
            lblRate.Text = ds.Tables("IBCARIP").Rows(inc).Item("NRate")
            lblOT.Text = ds.Tables("IBCARIP").Rows(inc).Item("OTRate")
            lblBnk.Text = ds.Tables("IBCARIP").Rows(inc).Item("BName") & ".." &                 ds.Tables("IBCARIP").Rows(inc).Item("ANumber") & ".." & ds.Tables("IBCARIP").Rows(inc).Item("AType")
            con.Close()
            ds.Tables("IBCARIP").DataSet.Clear()
            MaxRows = ds.Tables("IBCARIP").Rows.Count
            'inc = 0
        End if  
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

First the most important: you are open for SQL-Injection since you are not using sql-parameters but concatenating the query with user input.

The reason for the error is that you are trying to access the a `DataRow` in the `DataTable` without checking if there is at least one. But you are accessing the row with index `inc`, maybe the table does not contain so many rows. Why do you use a variable at all here?

```
da.Fill(ds, "IBCARIP")
If ds.Tables("IBCARIP").Rows.Count = 0 Then Return ' or something else

' here you can safely access the first row...
```

Here the long version with parameters:

```
Using con = New OleDbConnection(dbProvider & dbSource)
    Dim sql = "select * from Calculator where EmpCode=?"
    Using da = New OleDbDataAdapter(sql, con)
        da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmpCode", txtID.Text)
        da.Fill(ds, "IBCARIP")
        If ds.Tables("").Rows.Count > 0 Then
            Dim row = ds.Tables("IBCARIP").Rows(0)
            Dim SName = row.Field(Of String)("SName")
            Dim FName = row.Field(Of String)("FName")
            Dim sai = String.Format("{0}{1}", SName, FName)
            lblSAI.Text = sai
            ' ... '
        End If
    End Using
End Using
```

Comment: tim i will try your code on a different form and table  but it looks advanced for my level,, thank yoiu for the help though